# Executing SQL query in odoo 8

Tags: sql, odoo

I have my code like this :

```
        try:
            res = 0.0
            for employee in self.browse(cr, uid, localdict['employee'].id, context=context):
                cr.execute('SELECT sum(total)as sum FROM hr_payslip_line ' \
                           'WHERE slip_id = (SELECT max(id) FROM hr_payslip WHERE employee_id = %s  ) ' \
                           'AND affect_on_social_assurance = True ', (employee.id,))

                res = cr.dictfetchone()
```

It doesn't fetch any data, why is this? When I run the query in the pgAdmin it returnes the expected result.
but in this code return
res:(None,) when i debug it , 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjjfp.png)

Comment: Please, check `self.browse(cr, uid, localdict['employee'].id, context=context)`. It should return a single employee, not a list. Because you did  browse just 1 id.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually it return one employee but the problem in my query @Shpionus

Comment: if browse returns just one employee, `for` not works at all. Could you put `pdb.set_trace()` inside for cycle and check `employee.id`. Or  you can change log_level to check what exactly sql executes in you case.

Comment: I changed my code and make Screen Shoot to you ,please check it in the link after my description ,waiting your reply @Shpionus

Comment: I not see a reason of browse at all. You can use `localdict['employee'].id` instead of `employee.id`. Just print this value and try sql with this id.

Comment: I checked it the number of employee is true but the result of query still None @Shpionus

Comment: Syntactically all looks good now.  Sorry, I not see any other reason without other code (maybe inside translation you removed or updated some data before query). pdb and debug step by step will help you :)

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I found another one issue in your code: `res = cr.dictfetchone()` - so `res` is dict, but you trying to compare it with integer: `if res < minimum_range`